# Unexpected Behavior in wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm new to Python (and wxPython), and I was attempting to work through this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/).  When running this script, I end up with a strange window where the tc2's background is black, and all of the subsequent font turns to the color white.  Even when I comment out the text box, the font changes color for the rest of the window.  Code/output included below.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?
[image: Output Image]
I'm running Python 3.7 on MacOS with wxPython 4.x

'''python

```
def initUI(self):
    pnl = wx.Panel(self)
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


    font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
    font.SetPointSize(12)
    font = font.Bold()

    hBox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    cb1 = wx.CheckBox(pnl, label="SomeText")
    cb2 = wx.CheckBox(pnl, label="MoreText")

    btn1 = wx.Button(pnl, label="BTN 1", size=(70, 30))
    btn2 = wx.Button(pnl, label="BTN 2", size=(70, 30))

    st1 = wx.StaticText(pnl, label="A field")
    st2 = wx.StaticText(pnl, label="A Bigger Field")

    st1.SetFont(font)
    st2.SetFont(font)
    cb1.SetFont(font)
    cb2.SetFont(font)
    btn1.SetFont(font)
    btn2.SetFont(font)

    tc = wx.TextCtrl(pnl)
    tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

    hBox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.Right, border=8)
    hBox1.Add(tc, proportion=1)

    hBox2.Add(st2)

    hBox3.Add(tc2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    hBox4.Add(cb1)
    hBox4.Add(cb2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

    hBox5.Add(btn1)
    hBox5.Add(btn2, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.Bottom, border=5)

    vbox.Add(hBox1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP, border=10)
    vbox.Add((-1, 10))

    vbox.Add(hBox2, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=10)
    vbox.Add((-1, 10))

    vbox.Add(hBox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.Right | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    vbox.Add((-1, 25))

    vbox.Add(hBox4, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
    vbox.Add((-1, 25))

    vbox.Add(hBox5, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.Right, border=10)

    pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
```

'''

Comment: Do you have macOS's dark mode turned on?

Comment: I do have dark mode turned on.

Comment: @RobinDunn - turning off dark mode fixed the problem.  But this leads to the question of inconsistent application of styling rules across the widgets.  It's crazy to me that static labels render in black font and buttons in white font.  I'm sure there's a way that I haven't encountered yet, but can I manually force the font color (or 'set' the font color), to make this resistant to user color scheme preference?

Comment: Also - why do the two textcontrols render differently?

Comment: I don't remember details but I recall there was some discussion about some fixes related to dark mode in wxWidgets. They are likely coming in wxPython 4.1.x. The textctrl differences are probably due to differences in how the native control is set up for multi-line mode.

Comment: I don't know whether to call this solved - bug found, or leave it open because the core question is unanswered.  Wish we had some developer feedback here.